# How to load OSM file from local machine to the server using osm2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql

I wanted to upload the OSM file from my local machine to server using osm2pgsql, but the data is not imported.

I have just created the database s1(no table), do I need to create the table also, if yes how?

My osm2pgsql query

```
osm2pgsql -c -d osm -U s1 --password xx -k -H yy  /home/g/Downloads/niedersachsen-latest.osm.pbf pbf -r -S /home/g/default.style -s
```

I am getting an error

```
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Unknown file format '-S'.
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the error behavior ("not able to do it" is not useful)

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: does default.style exist?

Comment: I took a hint from a website and default. style I took it from GitHub, please suggest any other alternative, I need to import .osm.pbf

Comment: if that's the exact command then your syntax is wrong (e.g. it has to be `-r pbf`)! write that command more carefully. and check for unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the description of each command line parameter [here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md) or by running the command `osm2pgsql -h -v`

The parameter `-r` has the following description:

```
-r|--input-reader    Input format.
                        auto      - Detect file format. (default)
                        o5m       - Parse as o5m format.
                        xml       - Parse as OSM XML.
                        pbf       - OSM binary format.
```

In your command the value `pbf` is written before the `-r`, so it fails. You can put the parameter/value in the proper order or remove both of them, relying on the auto-detect default option.

```
osm2pgsql -c -d osm -U s1 --password xx -k -H yy  /home/g/Downloads/niedersachsen-latest.osm.pbf -r pbf  -S /home/g/default.style -s
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, that error is solved but getting another error Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Open failed for 'password': No such file or directory

Comment: don't write the password (`xx`) in the command line, it will be prompted.